# Having trouble with JavaScript's onscroll() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an online CV with a static box containing work experience. The idea is that when you scroll up or down the different companies and their associated information fades in and out. Here's my JavaScript code so far:

```
var employment_history_display = "Microsoft";
document.getElementById("employment_history_text").onwheel = function () {
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        if (employment_history_display == "SoftwareAG") {
            $("#SoftwareAG").animate({ opacity: '0' });
            $("#Microsoft").animate({ opacity: '1' });
            employment_history_display = "Microsoft";
        } else if (employment_history_display == "NAS") {
            $("#NAS").animate({ opacity: '0' });
            $("#SoftwareAG").animate({ opacity: '1' });
            employment_history_display = "SoftwareAG";
        };
    } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        if (employment_history_display == "SoftwareAG") {
            $("#SoftwareAG").animate({ opacity: '0' });
            $("#NAS").animate({ opacity: '1' });
            employment_history_display = "NAS";
        } else if (employment_history_display == "Microsoft") {
            $("#Microsoft").animate({ opacity: '0' });
            $("#SoftwareAG").animate({ opacity: '1' });
            employment_history_display = "SoftwareAG";
        };
    };
};
```

When the page loads the "Microsoft" div is visible and the other two are transparent. It works in that onwheel the next div fades in and the last one fades out. However, it quickly scrolls through both without stopping in the middle. I believe its due to onwheel returning multiple values thus the function repeats multiple times. Is there anyway to make it so the function defined under onwheel only works once?

Comment: You could easily add some kind of flag like `let hasRun = false;` which is checked before running, then flipped after running the first time. Alternatively add `{once:true}` to the addEventListener [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of setting in .onwheel

Answer (score 0):

A generic way to make a handler stop running once some arbitrary condition has been met is to remove the event handler from itself once the condition is met -- so eg, at the end of the first time the function executes, if you want it to only execute once, do this: `document.getElementById("employment_history_text").onwheel = function () {}`